# Use Openfiledialog to browser folder

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

Can I Use Openfiledialog  to  browser folder? Because I really hate using FolderBrowserDialog().

Comment: By `FolderBrowserDialog` - are you referring to the Windows XP-era single-tree-view dialog? Or are you referring to the Windows 7-era OFD-style folder browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue in one of my projects and found a solution. You can use it if you get the Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell nuget package and use the Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs namespace.
Use it as such:

```cs
CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog
    {
            IsFolderPicker = true
    };
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
    {
            // the selected directory is in dialog.FileName
    }
```